# Nokia 5110 display does not change on the key event in WeMos D1 with matrix keypad 3x4

Tags: arduino, display, lcd, keypad

I am working on a project with wemos, Nokia 5110 lcd and matric keypad 3x4.

I want to go to another screen on a specific key. The `keyEvent()` is the function I want to call when I trigger a key. The function is called correctly as it turns the led on when I press 3 on keypad, but the screen does not change.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_PCD8544.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(D7, D6, D5, D4, D3);

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {

    {'1','2','3'},
    {'4','5','6'},
    {'7','8','9'},
    {'*','0','#'}

};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {D6, D5, D4, D3};
byte colPins[COLS] = {D2, D1, D0};
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void keyEvent(int page, char key)
{

    if(page == 1 && key == '3')
    {

        digitalWrite(D8, HIGH); //This line works fine. But the below code is not executed.
        display.begin();
        display.clearDisplay();
        display.setCursor(0, 0);
        display.println("Line 4");
        display.println("Line 5");
        display.println("Line 6");
        display.display();
    
    }

  
}

int list = 1;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(D8, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

    char key = keypad.getKey();

    if (key)
    {
    
        keyEvent(list, key);
    
    }
    
    display.begin();
    display.setContrast(100);
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(0);
    display.setTextColor(BLACK);
    display.setCursor(0, 0);
    display.println("Line 1");
    display.println("Line 2");
    display.println("Line 3");
    display.display();
    
}
```

Comment: The screen does changed, it just that it changed and then quickly over-ride by your display codes in the loop. Add the `else` block in your main loop after the `if(key)` block.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to clear the screen on every loop. move all the screen setup function calls to `setup()`.